# What does the command 'sudo sh -e ~/Downloads' do?

Tags: command-line, sh, syntax

I am new to Ubuntu and learning how to use shell. Would someone please tell me what this command does:

```
sudo sh -e ~/Downloads
```

I know `sudo sh` will execute all commands in the shell as sudo. What is -e ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ush.htm) is a page describing the `sh` command.

> The sh command runs or processes jobs through the Bourne shell.
>
> The -e flag: If not interactive, exit immediately if any untested command fails. The exit status of a command is considered to be explicitly tested if the command is used to control an if, elif, while, or until; or if the command is the left hand operand of an "&&" or "||" operator.

Also see `man sh`.